Securing blinds when the tension rods don't cut it
I have a bunch of these top-down, bottom-up shades that have generally worked out great (at a fraction of the cheapest quote I got from the blinds and shades racket) with the qualification that the tension rods aren't invincible. This is partially because the frame isn't quite as deep as it ought to be.
So I need something to secure the top bar -- the part that doesn't move (ideally) and contains the gears and spools. I have an inch at either end to work with, probably uPVC.

I've considered a pair of U brackets) to provide little hooks in which the ends of the bar can rest. But I hope there's an easier and cheaper solution.
For example, a screw with an enormous head could work! Sort of like this slapdash guitar holder I made from some bolts to an old piece of furniture:

I suppose some towel pegs might work if I could attach them to the frame well enough. But maybe there's something even simpler. Thank you!


Off topic: Those threads are going to do ugly things to that beautiful guitar. You should install sleeves on them. Clear vinyl tubing might work well.

It would really help me see the problem if that first image wasn't a thumbnail. Where is a tension rod used? The last photo shows mounting clips, right?

How about you cut and apply a small square of double sided mounting tape to each contact surface? Example here in blue, image from your link:

Not a mounting film, but the thick, clear, rubbery tape that comes in a roll with release paper? 3M (Scotch) makes several varieties. Some are removable, some are permanent, some are weatherproof. The weatherproof, permanent variety has a shockingly strong grip that will prevent the shade from moving. The rubbery consistency will accommodate slight dimensional changes in the window frame resulting from temperature and humidity changes.
If you try this, remember that the tape's grip reaches the maximum after about 24 hours, so best to install it, wait a day and then abuse it if you wish to gain confidence in its performance.
